# "Discontinuity" of Gaussian Blur Around the Edges of an Image

Tags: c

I've been trying to implement a gaussian blur function of an nxn image with a gaussian kernel of specific radius rs=((int)2.75*sigma+0.5).

```
for (x=0;x<n;x++){
    for (y=0;y<n;y++){

        sum=0.0,wsum=0.0;

        //Position correction at the edges

        if(x-rs<0){
            ix=0;
        }
        else ix=rs;

        if(y-rs<0){
            iy=0;
        }
        else iy=rs;

        if (x+rs>n-1){
            jx=n-1-x;
        }
        else jx=rs;

        if (y+rs>n-1){
            jy=n-1-y;
        }
        else jy=rs;
        //Kernel mean value correction at the edges

        if ( x-rs < 0 ){
            meanx=x+((int)rs/2);
        }
        else meanx=x;

        if(y-rs<0){
            meany=y+((int)rs/2);
        }
        else meany=y;

        if (x+rs>n-1){
            meanx=x-((int)rs/2);
        }
        else meanx=x;

        if (y+rs>n-1){
            meany=y-((int)rs/2);
        }
        else meany=y;   


        for (i=x-ix;i<=x+jx;i++){
            for (j=y-iy;j<=y+jy;j++){

                weight=1/(2*M_PI*sigma*sigma)*exp(-((meanx-i)*(meanx-i)+(meany-j)*(meany-j))/(2*sigma*sigma));
                sum+=pic1.intenzity[i][j]*weight;
                wsum+=weight;
            }
        }

        pic2->intenzity[x][y]=((int)sum/wsum+0.5);

        fprintf(fw,"%d\n",pic2->intenzity[x][y]);   
    }
```

When I don't use the mean value correction at the edges the result looks like this:

[without mean value correction](https://s12.postimg.org/gqf8n7wi5/membrany_blur_sigma6_noedgecorrect.jpg)

and when I tried shifting the mean value of the kernel it creates a discontinuity also at the lower and right edge of the image:

[with shifting the mean value to rs/2](https://s14.postimg.org/a43bnhfdt/membrany_blur_sigma6_0_5rs.jpg)

I had to make the edge position corrections because the sum would overflow. Now it seems that the gaussian convolution suddenly jumps for some reason when it is at position rs from the upper and left edge for both x and y. I'd like to make it behave the same way as it does in the "interior" of the image, or perhaps make the intensities fade to 0 as the position approaches the edge.

I could potentially enlarge the image by rs, but it would cause problems with the edge position.

Thank you for any insightful help :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your calculations, but it could be a rounding error. You are converting to an integer every step of the way, you would get better results if you stored all of the data as floating point or double to do the calculations, then at the end round it to the nearest int. You have a huge margin of error the way you are converting to int every time.

Comment: I tried storing sum/wghtsum into a separate float matrix, and then writing it   again into the pixels in int, but it did the same thing.

Comment: I was referring to the casting to `int` that you do in nearly every step. Make sure all of your variables of of type double, and remove every instance of `(int)`, this truncates the decimal when it could contain important data, especially because you perform multiple calculations. You could be off by a substantial amount.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a typical filter kernel being applied to an image, in pseudocode. Lets use variables

```
# source[y][x]    Old image (read-only)
# target[y][x]    New image (write-only)
# image_height    Image height (y = 0 .. image_height-1)
# image_width     Image width (x = 0 .. image_width-1)
# filter[y][x]    Filter (weights) to be applied
# filter_height   Filter height (y = 0 .. filter_height-1)
# filter_width    Filter width (x = 0 .. filter_width-1)
# filter_y        Target pixel y coordinate in filter (filter_height/2)
# filter_x        Target pixel x coordinate in filter (filter_width/2)
```

where `filter_y = floor(filter_width / 2)` and `filter_x = floor(filter_height / 2)` if the filter is centered on the target pixel (ie. symmetric). The pseudocode is then roughly

```
For base_y = 0 to image_height - 1:

   # y range relative to base_y ...
   min_y = -filter_y
   max_y = filter_height - 1 - filter_y

   # ... must not exceed the image boundaries.
   If min_y + base_y < 0:
       min_y = -base_y
   End If

   If max_y + base_y < 0:
       max_y = -base_y
   End If

   If min_y + base_y >= image_height:
       min_y = image_height - 1 - base_y
   End If

   If max_y + base_y >= image_height:
       max_y = image_height - 1 - base_y
   End If

   For base_x = 0 to image_width - 1:

       # x range relative to base_x ...
       min_x = -filter_x
       max_x = filter_width - 1 - filter_x

       # ... must not exceed the image boundaries.
       If min_x + base_x < 0:
           min_x = -base_x
       End If

       If max_x + base_x < 0:
           max_x = -base_x
       End If

       If min_x + base_x >= image_width:
           min_x = image_width - 1 - base_x
       End If

       If max_x + base_x >= image_height:
           max_x = image_width - 1 - base_x
       End If

       ValueSum = 0
       WeightSum = 0

       For y = min_y to max_y:
           For x = min_x to max_x:
               Value = source[y + base_y][x + base_x]
               Weight = filter[y + filter_y][x + filter_x]
               ValueSum = ValueSum + Value * Weight
               WeightSum = WeightSum + Weight
           End For
        End For

        If WeightSum != 0:
            target[base_y][base_x] = ValueSum / WeightSum
        End If

    End For
End For
```

Inside the innermost loop, `[base_y][base_x]` refers to the target pixel, the one we are computing; and `[y+base_y][x+base_x]` refers to the source pixel weighted by `[y+filter_y][x+filter_x]`. `x` and `y` are relative values, ranging from `-filter_x` and `-filter_y` to `filter_width-1-filter_x` and `filter_height-1-filter_y`, respectively.

As long as `ValueSum` and `WeightSum` has sufficient range, the same code works whether image and filter data is integer or floating-point.

The tricky part, and the part causing the artefacts the OP sees, is how to calculate the `min_y`, `max_y`, `min_x`, and `max_x` correctly.

To debug, remove the two innermost loops, and instead print something like

```
printf("y = %d, ymin = %d (%d), ymax = %d (%d)\n",
       base_y, min_y, min_y + base_y, max_y, max_y + base_y);
```

inside the outer loop (no need to print it for every `base_x`!), and

```
printf("x = %d, xmin = %d (%d), xmax = %d (%d)\n",
       base_x, min_x, min_x + base_x, max_x, max_x + base_x);
```

once in the innermost loop (no need to print it again for every `base_y`), in e.g. `if (y == 0) printf("...");`. This outputs `image_width + image_height` lines, and lets you verify whether the ranges you define are correct.

In OP's case, the ranges are incorrect near the edges of the image; i.e., some of their `if` clauses corresponding to above pseudocode compute/assign incorrect `min_x`, `max_x`, `min_y`, and `max_y` values.

Comment: In short, this answer's point is to offset the weighted sum of the kernel for each pixel so the effective kernel sum always adds up to one. He's doing this by counting up the kernel cell values ever time it is effectively applied, and dividing the resulting value with it. Neat solution, I like it! (Please correct me if I'm wrong)